# Catch 22 Situation With Quickbooks (Can't allow app to connect because can't open QuickBooks)

Tags: sdk, quickbooks

(Note, I believe this is different than the previous questions I've seen on this because those all appear to apply to earlier versions or are doing something different process-wise. So, thos answers haven't helped me in this case.)

I have an application that connects to QB running fine on one machine. However, when I moved it to another machine, and I try to connect when QB IS NOT running, I get an error that "This application is not allowed to log into this QuickBooks company data file automatically. The QuickBooks administrator can grant permission for an automatic login through the Integrated Application preferences."

Ordinarily when that happens, I run the program and I'm prompted to add the application, and I do. However, on this machine I'm getting "QuickBooks can't start because it is already running. Only QB Accountant, QuickBooks bookkeeper and QuickBooks enterprise can open more than one company file" whenever I try that. I also don't see a way to manually add the application.

This is QB Desktop 2014 (350-569) and SDK13. The chain is an executable to a helper dll to the QB dll to QB.

Does anyone have any ideas as to what the issue may be?

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone have any ideas as to what the issue may be?

Yep.

This is your answer:

> However, on this machine I'm getting "QuickBooks can't start because it is already running. Only QB Accountant, QuickBooks bookkeeper and QuickBooks enterprise can open more than one company file

QuickBooks is already running *on this computer*. The other computer has nothing to do with this issue.

Your first step should be to reboot, and try again.

You can also check Windows Task Manager (taskmgr.exe) and look for the QBW32.exe process. If it's running, kill it, and then try to start QuickBooks again.

You can also check that QuickBooks is not set stay running in the background (Edit > Preferences > General > Keep QuickBooks running for faster start-ups).

You might also check to make sure your app, and QuickBooks are both running with the same user privileges. e.g. if QuickBooks is set to start as Administrator, and your app isn't, it can cause these errors. Try to run both as the Windows Administrator and see if you have better luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. The issue is the error I get when I run the application when QB is NOT open. Then I get the "This application is not allowed to log into this QuickBooks company data file automatically.<br/>  The QuickBooks administrator can grant permission for an automatic login through the Integrated Application preferences" error. The only way, that I'm aware of, to get that permission set is to run the program while QB is running.

Comment: Please ignore previous reply. I appreciate you taking the time. The issue is the error I get when I run the application when QB is NOT open, as above. Then I get the "This application is not allowed" error.  The only way I know of to get that permission set is to run the app while QB is running. You then get a prompt which allows you to grant permission for the app to access QB.  That's why I'm stuck. The first error requires QB to be running, the second says I can't use the app while QB is running. Also, the application is perfectly happy running while QB is open on the other computer.

Comment: The very first time you connect an app on any given computer, QuickBooks *must* be open. Then, to connect *without* QuickBooks open, two things need to happen: 1. in Edit > Preferences > Integrated Apps the option to allow unattended connections needs to be checked off and 2. the company file path needs to be specified when you connect. You will also need to make sure that the option to "Keep QuickBooks running for faster startups" is NOT enabled, because that will cause problems. Have you done all of those things?

Comment: Also, I think you're confused about what the error message is telling you. The second error message *is not* telling you that can't use the app while QB is running. It's telling you that QB is *already* running, and that it can't connect to the existing running instance of QuickBooks. These are two very different things.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I turned off the QB preference to run in the background, lowered the UAC level, and ran both programs as admins, and they it work. I really appreciate the advice.